# How to know gradle task error message in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I ran 'generateGrammarSource` gradle task in IntelliJ and it went red.

[image]

Now, how to know exact error message?

Comment: It seems, there is a button for it, left from `Run build`, to change th way Console shows you the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on "/ab" icon in the top-left of the window, and you'll switch to console view where you can find details of the error.